# Definition of EntryPoint via composition in F#

Tags: f#, ocaml

I was trying to get a better understanding of the Functional way of coding, and just wrote a small program to print back the factorial of a user-entered number:

```
open System

let fact n = let rec factiter init acc = 
                      if init = 0 then acc
                      else factiter (init - 1) init*acc
             factiter n 1


let dropStrArr (argv: string []) = ignore argv

let factComp = Console.ReadLine >> Int32.Parse >> fact >> Console.WriteLine >> fun () -> 0

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = (dropStrArr >> factComp) argv
```

This worked fine but then I thought `main` could be defined purely by composition and tried:

```
let main = dropStrArr >> factComp
```

which I thought would work, but although it compiles, it simply exits immediately upon running.

There are different types in the two scenarios:
    `unit -> int`
when main is defined with its argument, versus
    `(unit -> int)`
when using composition.

I'm probably missing about the type system, so my question is why can't main just be defined via composition here?

Comment: It's just a quirk of how F# is compiled to the underlying IL representation. No specific reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that writing point-free style in F# has consequences.

Functions which are partially applied, get compiled to `FSharpFunc` and are subsequently called with `Invoke`.

To illustrate:

```
let mul a b = a + b
let mul2 = mul 2 //point-free
let mul2P a = mul 2 a //pointed
```

`mul2P` look something like you'd expect (in equivalent C#)

```
static int mul2P(int a) { return mul(2, a); }
```

while `mul2` becomes

```
class mul2Impl : FSharpFunc<int, int>
{       
    public int a;
    mul2Impl(int a) { this.a = a; }

    public override int Invoke(int b)
    {
        return mul(this.a, b);
    }
}
```

So when you write `let main argv` it becomes a simple static method which just calls the other two `FSharpFunc` with

```
factComp.Invoke(dropStrArr.Invoke(argv));
```

But when you compose it, `main` becomes an `FSharpFunc` and there's no more [a static main method as is required](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Asti, I hadn't even considered it being an implementation detail. I guess one should always look at the IL.